# Join 2 tables from different DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I join 2 tables from different DB with SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply just use multipart identifier names if they are in the same server.

```
SELECT *
FROM [database_1].[dbo].[table_1] t1
JOIN [database_2].[dbo].[table_2] t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
```

If not you can use linked servers and 4-part names.

```
SELECT *
FROM [database_1].[dbo].[table_1] t1
JOIN [linked_server].[database_2].[dbo].[table_2] t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
```